# Junk Characters || SSJS Fire Entry || The Japanese characters show Junk when stored in DataExtension

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, ssjs

I am using a simple SSJS code from [here](https://gist.github.com/camrobert/b32f36cf6bfa4ddf7db0df2f0e43e7a0#file-ssjs-get-sfmc-token-post-sfmc-rest-api).
I have updated the Fire Entry API end point as below.

```SSJS
/*=== SFMC REST API === */
  var payload = {   "ContactKey": Account_ID,
                                "EventDefinitionKey":eventkey,
                                "EstablishContactKey": true, 
                                "Data": {   "Account_ID":Account_ID,
                                            "Person_Email": Person_Email, 
                                            "Contact_Salutation":Contact_Salutation, 
                                            "Contact_First_Name": Contact_First_Name, 
                                            "Contact_Last_Name":Contact_Last_Name
                                           
                                        }   
                            };
  var route = "interaction/v1/events";  
 Write("<br><br>payload = " + Stringify(payload) + "<br><br>");
//  Write("<br><br>restUrl = " + restUrl +route+  "<br><br>");
  var contentType = 'application/json'; 
  var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
  var headerValues = ["Bearer "+accessToken];
  var result = HTTP.Post(restUrl+route, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
  if (result.StatusCode == 201) {
    var responseJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);
   // Write(Stringify(responseJSON)+"<br><br>"); //response
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("Error calling API");
  }
```

- When I Output the 'Payload' in cloud page, the Japanese characters display in Japanese.

> However when they get stored in Data Extension they display as **???1 ???????????**
> [image]

- Also I noticed, when I use the same payload from POSTMAN, it works like a champ and Japanese charecters are correctly displayed on both Cloud page as well as in DataExtension!

Any help/advice on this! I know this is something to do with 'UTF-8' encoding... but just looking where to add/Syntax of adding it!

Comment: It says this in the document `If you use UTF-8 characters in a payload for the Rest API, change the Content-Type header to: application/json; charset=UTF-8` https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postEvent.html

Comment: This worked thanks @DucLe

Comment: Interesting question, it is the first time I am aware about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
var contentType = 'application/json; charset=UTF-16';
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this worked @JonasLamberty